# Error when running selenium via C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Am trying to run a selenium suite using this code which runs perfectly on my local machine but giving an error when deployed on the server saying cannot find the specified file. Any help would be appreciated?

**the program and argument:**

> program = "java";
>   Arguments = " -jar selenium-server.jar and rest  of the argument as in selenium v give browser port and results and testcase file";

```
    standardErr = String.Empty;
    standardOut = String.Empty;

    if (!silent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start" + program + " " + arguments);
    }

    Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
    {
        //execute from the specific working directory if specified
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
    }

    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = program;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();

    if (!silent)
    {
        if (proc.StandardOutput != null)
        {
            standardOut = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(standardOut);
        }
    }

    if (proc.StandardError != null)
    {
        standardErr = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(standardErr);
    }

    proc.StandardOutput.Close();
    proc.StandardError.Close();
    return standardErr;
```

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "csharp". The language is "C#".

Comment: thanks john saunders for letting me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the local machine and the server have the same environment settings (Path, classpath etc.)

Next (if the problem remains) try to find out what file can't be found (Eventlog, other logs)

Comment: i tried checking the event-log there was a dns errors...even i think your ans is the solution to my problem thanks up-voted, i would mark it as an answer once its up running on the server.